# Map tt_news links to work with tx_news extension in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I'm using tx_news with imported news entries from tt_news.
The import worked well, but some news contain "old" links in the body field of this form

```
/index.php?id=10&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=123&tx_ttnews[mode]=single&tx_ttnews[backPID]=2&no_cache=1
```

Can these links be "mapped" somehow to work with tx_news?

Using Typo3 7.6.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, this is not possible. However there are several options I am thinking of. In general those links should be defined by using the [EXT:linkhandler](https://github.com/cobwebch/linkhandler)

1) Convert manually: Sounds sad but if not too many links are there, it is certainly the fastest one.

2) Use one of the hooks of TYPO3 which are used during the bootstrapping and do custom redirects. E.g. `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/index_ts.php']['preprocessRequest']`.

3) Hook into the error handling and redirect right before showing any error page. One example to check out could be an ext I did: https://github.com/georgringer/fast_redirect. It must be certainly modified to fit your needs.

---

What you can actually do as well, which I did for a big import a while ago: Remove all news records again, truncate the table and use any PHP script and fill up the table `tx_news_domain_model_news`with the same amount of news entries found in `tt_news` and set the uid to the one of tt_news and set the import_source field to `TT_NEWS_IMPORT` and the import_id field as well to the uid of the tt_news uid. After that, the import will pick the dummy `tx_news_domain_model_news` record, found by `findOneByImportSourceAndImportId()` and will enrich it with the regular data. You will end with news records having the same uid.

Comment: What should converted links look like exactly?
If I use this `index.php?id=10&tx_news_pi1[news]=123` the correct news won't be found, since the "old" news uid is different from the new one.

Comment: hmm, ok, thought there would be a way to catch/hook into some part of tx_news extension to fetch news entries by the database field "import_id".
Can't this method "findOneByImportSourceAndImportId()" in NewsRepository class be used therefore somehow?

Comment: I've updated the uids directly in tx_news_domain_model_news, because tt_news isn't available anymore.
thx for the great support! :)